# ColdFusion - Converting a query into CFC setters

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am converting an older site to CF 10 and wanted to bring forward some of my helper code.

The code looks at a query, finds things that are in our instance, and populates them:

```
<cffunction name="populateSelf">
    <cfargument name="source" type="query" required="yes" />
    <cfif arguments.source.recordcount EQ 1>
        <cfloop list="#arguments.source.columnlist#" index="local.col">
            <cfif structKeyExists(variables.instance, local.col)>
                <cfset variables.instance[local.col] = arguments.source[local.col]) />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif> <!--- one record? --->
</cffunction>
```

I have replaced the `structKeyExists(variables.instance, local.col)` with a handy evaluation of our current properties using 'getMetaData()', but I am having trouble with the next line: `<cfset variables.instance[local.col] = arguments.source[local.col]) />`

If I change it to `<cfset this[local.col] =arguments.source[local.col] />`, it ignores the implicit setters and just puts the results in the this scope...

In order to try and call our setters, I tried this bit of code:

```
<cfset setValue =arguments.source[local.col] />
<cfset evaluate("set#local.col#('#setValue#')" />
```

but this seems complicated and error prone (have to escape any "'"s in the strings too).

What is the best way to use a query to load some or all of a CFCs properties without having to explicitly call `this.setPROPERTYNAME(query.COLUMN)` possibly several dozen times????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So if I am reading all this correctly, your question is actually "how do I call a method dynamically?", and all the rest of it is set dressing?

You can use a string to set the dynamic variable name, then set a function reference to that, then call the function via the reference:

```
myMethodName = "set#local.col#";
myMethodReference = this[myMethodName];
myMethodReference(arguments.source[local.col]);
```

Comment: yes! "How do I call a method dynamically!" I could not think of the correct verbs to use... stoopid holiday, my brain is leaking out.

Comment: Hey Stephen... @baynezy's answer is better than mine! You should run with what he suggested rather than what I suggested.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call methods dynamically you can use cfinvoke

```
<cfinvoke method="set#property#">
```

Make sense?

Comment: Actually yeah good call. Saves the horsing around with function references.

Comment: Ok, I tried <cfinvoke method="set#property#"> but I can not get it to accept an argument to set because I do not know what to name the argument. (I tried <cfinvokeargument name="#property#" value="#value#" /> with no luck)...

Comment: Ah ok I see your problem. Do you not have a naming convention for your argument name for your setters in the same way you have a naming convention for your method itself? If you do then you can just additionally use cfinvokeargument in addition to what I put before.

Comment: Can you not simply use an argumentcollection for that? Or am I missing something (cc @baynezy)

Comment: @AdamCameron you can use argumentCollection as well. The issue he has is that he doesn't know the name of the argument to pass into the method. So your way he gets to just get away with the parameter order.

Comment: @baynezy Duh [slaps head in a sign of stupidity]. Gotcha. I misread the preceding post, and was thinking they didn't know the name of the key holding the argument value (to pass to the method), but yes... you mean the actual name of the argument as far as the method is concerned. Sorry: brain fart.